# Getting content from a function to another without needing to copy paste the code

Tags: javascript, function

1.I have two functions

```
functionName=()=>{
let example='value'
//and more data
}
newFunction=()=>{}
```

2.I want both of these functions to be connected, but once I created the second one I no longer had access to the data in the first function, the question is: how to I use that data from the previous function in the new function without needing to copy and paste the code?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because of too broad. There are a lot of ways to do that: *global variable, return type, callback, module...*

Comment: what you need from first function? Some value from ajax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If only data persistence across methods is your issue then you should be considered declaring a variable in global scope

For Example:-

```
var p1 = 3;
var p2 = 2;
var p3;

function myFunction1() {
   this.p3 = this.p1 * this.p2;
}

function myfunction2() {
 return this.p3;
}
```

Here you can access the value of p3, I hope this would solve your issue